# Blazor best way to avoid rendering child component while changes are being made to parent

Tags: blazor

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsqnK.png[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsqnK.png%5BFilter) Component and Child Dashoard][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsqnK.png)

Is there a better way to keep from filtering the data while in the parts Dashboard Component while the DashboardConfiguration component is having items clicked on an off than using something like a button or checkbox to *apply filters* and just don't fetch/filter data unless FilterIsSet in PartsDashboard OnInitializedAsyc

I considered trying to implement this as a form and not filter until the form was submitted as well.
This seems like something that should be fairly easy to do but I feel as if I am missing something.

Comment: Turned out the simpler solution was to add a plain button and just assign values to the cascaded parameters when the button is pressed that way the child component only changes on click.